# How to create a BIG cache table without increasing the LOG file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We want to create a BIG cache table (30 Mio records), for optimizing database queries.
This cache table will be on a separate disk.

We are using simple database logging.

**Problem:** When we insert the data into the cache, then the LOG File on the main tablespace begins to increase until the INSERT is ready, then the log file goes back to normal.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to insert millions of records into a table without the log file being increased at all?

We don't need an "undo" option, so in fact: Can you insert data into a table outside of any transactionm, i.e. without having a ROLLBACK option?

**Also, Question 2:** Is there a better method to create big tables with cached data ?

Comment: No you can't do an insert with no transaction. That is part of the ACID principle. If you are doing a single insert of a million rows your log file is going to grow during the operation. You can decrease the amount of growth by doing your inserts in batches.

Comment: You might want to also look at BULK INSERT.

Comment: You might want to think about a no-sql solution for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input! So in fact, there are only two solutions:

- BULK INSERT. Thanks, this is a good input, but this only takes FILES as input.
- Splitting up the INSERT into multiple smaller batches I did this. Wrote a procedure with a cursor loop, which inserts a smaller part of the data with every loop.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has various ways of performing [minimally logged inserts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This requires the `SIMPLE` recovery model among other things. When doing this the amount of log generated is small because mostly allocations are logged.

There is no way to turn off transactions or disable rollback support. Those are certainly reasonable feature requests but it's not possible right now.

You can also try reducing the size of the data that is written, for example by using data compression or using a clustered columnstore index (which can have amazing compression).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that implicit transactions are off. That way you won't build up data inside the current transaction.

In SQL Server 2014, there is an in-memory table option for this sort of thing, but that won't work if you are stuck on 2008.

Comment: There is no way to turn off transactions in SQL Server.

Comment: Agreed, but this will help reduce overhead IF the temporary table is being built via multiple SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can not omit transaction log, but you can use [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) with BATCHSIZE option for reduction of transaction log size.